# Rails HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many, self-reference, squeel

I have self reference `habtm` assotiation.

```
class Label < AR::B
   has_and_belongs_to_many :a_label, :class_name => "Label",
            :join_table => "a_labels",
            :foreign_key => "label_id",
            :association_foreign_key => "a_label_id",
            :uniq => true
end
```

But when i create query (with `squeel`):

```
Label.select{:title}.where do
        id.in(Label.select{:a_label_id}.joins(:a_labels).where{
            labels.title.in(list)
          })
```

Schema:

```
 labels:
 id | title | description | created_at

 a_labels
 label_id | a_label_id
```

I got error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError:
   Association named 'a_labels' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Where I was mistaken?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to add an "s" to your association name.  Instead of "a_label", change to "a_labels".

```
class Label < AR::B
  has_and_belongs_to_many :a_labels, ...
    ...
end
```